# Can row-based counters be made to behave like SEQUENCE or IDENTITY?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

SEQUENCE and IDENTITY deliver globally unique incrementing values across all sessions and transactions, regardless of isolation level, and they are not affected by transaction rollbacks. Is it possible to get the same behaviour with row-based counters and, if so, how can it be done?

The biggest problem seems to be performing the counter update outside the scope of any transaction that may be open. Can a server link itself to call its own procedures in a sort of 'remote mode' that punches through any currently active transactions and isolation modes?

The 'remote' call could then invoke a simple procedure like this running in auto-commit mode:

```
create or alter procedure dbo.next_value (@id int, @result int = null output)
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    update dbo.RowBasedCounters
        set @result = counter_value = counter_value + 1
        where counter_id = @id;
    return @result;
end;
```

Background: we need exactly the same behaviour as that of SEQUENCE or IDENTITY as kind of file/transfer counters for external communication partners, three independent counters for each partner. However, using SEQUENCE or IDENTITY is not really feasible since these require a separate named database object for each counter (i.e. they are singletons and not keyed), and in any case there are thousands of partners and hence many thousand counters.

P.S.: These counters number transfers (EDI files) and transfer attempts between communication partners in the German healthcare system; files are numbered for each pair of partners starting with 1 each year, transfer attempts are numbered eternally modulo 1000, also for each pair of partners. **Numbers must be sequential.** The numbering schemes are defined by standards and outside of our control.

We are using MS SQL Server 2014.

*Note: sequence gaps due to transaction rollbacks etc. are not a problem, as such exceptions can logged and hence documented automatically. Also, occasional dropouts could be investigated after the fact and documented if and when a partner calls to inquire about the reason for a gap in the sequence, as long as those gaps are very few and far between.*

Comment: What is the counter actually used for here; is it not something that could be obtained by using `ROW_NUMBER` instead?

Comment: There really isn't a way to deal with this the way you are proposing. But that doesn't mean there aren't some viable options. Is there any reason that each counter has to be unique per partner? It sounds to me like an identity should work for you and unless you truly need to allow for duplicate numbers across partners you could do this with a single table or sequence. You could even do this if you also stored the PartnerID. Then you could use ROW_NUMBER to get the sequential values. There are many ways to deal with this situation.

Comment: What you have above could easly suffer from race conditions, if you're using that for an update. Also `RETURN` is for stating the success of an SP, not for returning data. `0`means success and anything else means failure. You should be using an `OUTPUT`parameter here.

Comment: @Larnu: These counters number transfers (EDI files) and transfer attempts between communication partners in the German healthcare system; files are numbered for each pair of partners starting with 1 each year, transfer attempts are numbered eternally modulo 1000, also for each pair of partners. The numbering schemes are defined by standards and outside of our control.

Comment: That doesn't mean much to me; I don't know anything about the German Healthcare System. But that doesn't say to me "No, we can't use `ROW_NUMBER`.", as myself and @SeanLange have suggested.

Comment: I understand you can't control the numbering schemes. But a single table to hold transfers would be sufficient here. If you store the PartnerID and the datetime of the transfer you can leverage ROW_NUMBER to any numbering scheme easily.

Comment: For example, if you always needed the value to be prefixed by `'ABC_DE_HS'`, followed by a 10 digit number that is divisible by 1000 then something like `CONCAT('ABC_DE_HS',RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Partner ORDER BY DateColumn)),10)` would achieve that.

Comment: If these numbers must be perfectly sequential, you can't use identities and sequences in any case, as they leave gaps if transactions are rolled back. This willingness to leave gaps is also what allows them to efficiently produce values, concurrently if necessary. If gapless value are necessary, you need row locks one way or another -- either when incrementing a counter or when inserting a row if you're using `ROW_NUMBER`. An explicit locking hint is enough, coupled with the promise to never use data until the transaction has successfully committed -- external transactions aren't relevant.

Comment: FWIW, if gaps are not a problem, I have maintained a solution where sequences where created dynamically based on a table with triggers on it. Admittedly then we're talking dozens of sequences, not thousands, but still. In terms of absolute number of objects permitted, SQL Server would have no trouble with thousands of independent sequence objects, though using them requires generating dynamic code, which could get awkward.

Answer (score 0):

As Larnu and I have both said you can leverage ROW_NUMBER for this against a single table pretty easily.

I created a Transfers table and created some sample data to represent having 2 partners. I am using sys.objects to generate some random dates from 2018 and 2019, you might need to adjust this if you don't have objects created in both those years but seems unlikely. This will generate sequential numbers for each partner and it restarts each year. Hopefully this will be a good starting point.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transfers') is not null
    drop table #Transfers

create table #Transfers
(
    TransferID int identity
    , PartnerID int
    , TransferDate datetime
)

insert #Transfers
select top 5 1, create_date
from sys.objects
where create_date > '20180101' --to limit to only two years to demonstrate partitioning
order by NEWID()

insert #Transfers
select top 5 2, create_date
from sys.objects
where create_date > '20180101' --to limit to only two years to demonstrate partitioning
order by NEWID()

select *
    , MySeq = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by PartnerID, datepart(year, TransferDate) order by TransferDate desc)
from #Transfers
```

Comment: Sean, how is inserting/counting rows any different from updating/querying a counter field as far as the transaction isolation and rollback issues are involved? How does your approach differ in that regard from `update foo set counter = counter + 1 where id = @id`? I simply cannot see it.

Comment: There is no race condition here. But the values are not static either. If a row gets deleted or a row inserted the numbering sequence will adjust dynamically. Maybe that is a bad thing in your situation.

Comment: Sean, your approach seems to suffer from problems that are analogous to those one would get using `(select max(id) from foo) + 1` instead of a an IDENTITY column or a SEQUENCE. Parallel transactions can cause multiple dispensation of the same value, and rollbacks can cause later values to be renumbered; the exact effects depend on isolation level. AFAICS your approach solves neither the problem of 'punching through' transaction isolation nor the rollback issue; it merely results in having a table with one row for each different *value* as opposed to having one row for each different *counter*.

Comment: Well when you have to sequential numbering with zero gaps you are creating an impossible situation. No matter what you do you will run into these potential issues.

Comment: Sean, occasional rare gaps due to rollbacks or deletion are not a problem, as I said elsewhere. They are an inevitable byproduct of enabling concurrent processing without company-wide global serialization à la PDOXUSRS.NET of old. The problem I'm trying to solve is to run `update T set n = n + 1 where k = @k` effectly outside the scope of any currently active transaction and/or isolation mode, in the same way as SEQUENCE and IDENTITY do. I've already got code working via SSMS, Delphi (ADO) and Fox (ODBC), however, I still need to do some due diligence on it before I can write it up.